# Is it possible detect Value or Type in template using traits?

Tags: templates, c++11, type-traits

Is possible using traits to deduce if a template argument is Value or a Type?

```
template <typename A>
void function(){
    if(is_value<A>()::value)
        cout<<"A is value"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"A is type"<<endl;
}

int main(){
    function<int>(); 
    function<3>();
}
```

outputs

```
"A is type"
"A is value"
```

Comment: as you can immagine, that would be tremendously usefull. This would allows, along with lambdas very nice things :D

Comment: A value is not a type, and `template<typename T>` expects a type. No dice, there's no "catch all" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per 14.3/1 Standard:

> There are three forms of template-argument, corresponding to the three
>   forms of  template-parameter: **type**, **non-type** and **template**.

And per 14.3.1/1 Standard:

> A template-argument for a template-parameter which is a **type** shall be a **type-id**.

Since your template argument is **type**, you should pass a **type-id** as template argument. `3` is not a **type-id**. So, it is impossible in your way.

You could only add a function with **non-type** template-argument:

```
template <class A>
void function()
{
    std::cout << "A is type" << std::endl;
}

template <int A>
void function()
{
    std::cout << "A is value" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    function<int>();
    function<3>();
}
```

Comment: nice, but that requires a different function for every possible "value's type". so basically is not possible doing what I expected :(.